# Node 101: app.use ReferenceError [route] not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am new to Node/Express, and have a basic question about routing as I am getting the following error message:

```
app.use('/edu', edu);
                ^
ReferenceError: edu is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ronitelman/Dropbox/happy/happy/app.js:29:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ronitelman/Dropbox/happy/happy/bin/www:7:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

app.js:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/edu', edu);
```

File structure:

```
> root
  > ...
  > routes
    | about.js
    | edu.js
    | index.js
    | users.js
```

edu.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard', { layout: 'layout_edu' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Additionally, I wanted to know if I should use the 'extends layout' in my dashboard.jade file, or if I should define the layout in the route

dashboard.jade

```
extends layout //- or   res.render('dashboard', { layout: 'layout_edu' }); ?

block content
  include ./nav/nav_layout.jade
  .wrapper
    include ./home/home.jade
    include ./home/benefits.jade      
    include ./home/students.jade
    include ./home/teachers.jade    
    include ./home/admin.jade
    include ./home/analytics.jade                             
    include ./home/tech.jade
    include ./home/featured.jade
```

Comment: Did you require Edu in your Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you require your `edu` module in your `app.js` file. Usually at the top of the file you would need something like `var edu = require('./routes/edu.js');` (which asks node to load your `edu.js` file in the `routes` directory).

Concerning your second question, the way you make your `extends` call in your Jade file should be OK. For more clarity and to avoid mistakes, you should reference it by its filename, like `extends ./layout.jade` (if `layout.jade` is in the same directory as `dashboard.jade`)

Comment: thank you for pointing out that I had missed requiring the edu module and for the tip on using extends in my Jade file.